# Localizing dates samsung galaxy

Tags: android, date, localization

I’m facing a strange problem localizing dates.
When running my app on emulator with Swedish locale (sv) everything works fine.
Dates are formatted according to: yyyy-MM-dd

However, when I run the same app on a Samsung galaxy S4 dates end up as:
dd-MM-yyyy

Locale.getDefault().getLanguage() evaluates to “sv” in both cases.

I use the following snippet to get the date string

```
public static String getDateString(Date date) {
        return android.text.format.DateFormat.getDateFormat(App.getContext()).format(date);
    }
```

Localization works fine when it comes to the rest of the UI.

Any ideas?

Comment: Looking at the documentation, it says `In cases where the system does not provide a suitable pattern, this class offers the getBestDateTimePattern(Locale, String) method.`  documentation here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateFormat.html  Also note for Locale you could use this:  `Locale l = new Locale("sv_SE");`

Comment: I already faced problems like you, so i discovered a nice util class http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I looked at these methods but I still find the behavior strange. If I need to create a Locale in order to use a formatting method I can still just check the language and so something like
`If (Locale.getDefault().getLanguage().equals(“sv”)) 
return new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(date);`
Anyways thanks, I’ll try to look in to the Util class or try to use getBestDateTimePattern

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to have a different date format on two devices with the same locale set.

In Android 4.x the settings preferences on the device allow users to set a date format that is not the default date format for the locale selected on the device.

The option is available via; Settings > Date & Time > Choose Date Format

[image]
This is not just an option on Samsung devices but can be also found on stock Android 4.x. However on Android 5.1 the option seems to have been removed.

Comment: Thank you! That makes the problem less (not at all) strange. If I find some very general solution i'll post it here.

Comment: @SvenPersson Glad it helped. If the date string is for display in the UI it is best to respect the settings of the device. If the date is for storage or transmission you can force the format of the string using SimpleDateFormat. Is there some other issue?